# Python / win32com / Michrosoft Visio / Macro

Tags: python, visio

I need to convert many visio files, but when opining them there is a msg coming from Windows which asks a confirmation.

Here is my call :

```
application = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
application.AlertResponse = 7
```

Msg occurs whatever the alertresponse is

As my working environment doesn't allow me to change the preferences of visio, is there a way to bypass this msg with python ?

thanks

EDIT

Here is the message (which is more a security issue about macros)

https://photos.app.goo.gl/HbGC4fRadQZCUxj89

Comment: Which confirmation do you mean (please share screenshot) ? These confirmations appear when you open the document manually ?

Comment: Please try add line `application.Settings.ShowFileOpenWarnings = False`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried ShowFileOpenWarnings false  but no luck

Comment: Sorry I cant read in French. Tell me please what written at your screenshot ?

Comment: It raises a security issue, and asks for confirmation about activate or deactivate the macros for the visio document (by default, we don't want to activate the macros)

Comment: Sad, but thuth: MS Visio dont support [msoAutomationSecurity property](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/office.msoautomationsecurity)

Comment: it seems OpenEx can do the job, but I can't pass the second argument required as &H80 (visOpenMacrosDisabled) `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '&H80' `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247328/discussion-between-surrogate-and-fransua).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to use

```
doc = application.Documents.OpenEx(path_input + file,128)
```

to prevent the warning, as 128 is the decimal number of H80

Comment: Great ! Please add this trick as answer. It can help to other users :)